# ElasticSearch partial string multiple fields

Tags: string, elasticsearch, partial

```
    My index has the following fields:
```

(1) title: with simple analysed string.

(2) cuisine: with string values such as 'International|Buffet|Asian'.

```
    I use the following query strings:
```

(1)

```
"query_string": {
    "fields": ["title", " cuisine"],
    "query": "*buffet*"
}
```

(2)

```
"multi_match": {
    "query": "*buffet*",
    "type": "phrase_prefix",
    "fields": ["title", " cuisine"]
}

None of them works as both return empty result. Any advice and insight is appreciated. Thanks!
```

Here is a snippet of my mapping:

```
{
"search.weeloy.asia": {
    "mappings": {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "cuisine": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index. `GET index/type/_mapping`

Comment: How to add it? I tried and it gives error message.

Comment: Did you replace `index` and `type` with your `indexname` and `type name`. If yes, what error d you get.

Comment: I tried to copy paste my mapping here but couldn't. Either it is too long or it complains only having code in the message

Comment: Okk.. share he mapping for `title and cuisine` fields

Comment: @KokHowTeh "match" family of queries does  not support wildcard characters. query_String query should work. You should update your question with mapping as well as exact query that you are firing.

Comment: @KokHowTeh Your "cuisine" field has a space character. it is " cuisine". Fix it and it should work.

Comment: @krrish That's sharp. Thanks for the catch!!! ;)

Comment: @krrish I tried the wildcard queries with the multi_match. It returns the same results as query_string. All of the 5 multi_match types return the same results as the query_string. What did you mean it does not support wildcard? What do I miss? Thanks!

Comment: OK. I have tried again match indeed does NOT work with wildcard partial string.

Comment: @KokHowTeh I have not tried it, I thought multi_match belongs to match family. Sorry, if I created confusion. Check bottom of this page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html. Also check the  version you are using, may be wildcard is not supported in latest version of ES in multi_match query

Comment: Hi, I notice that the scores are always different. As a result, although the results returned are the same but the sequence is always different. Any comment on that?